# Is there any hidden side effect of initialising NSString object twice

Tags: ios, objective-c

If we initialise NSString object twice then is there any issue or side effects?

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init];
str = [str init];
```

Comment: The second line is illegal. It's that simple. It is illegal to say `init` anywhere outside of the same line where you say `alloc`. And it is illegal to say `alloc` without saying `init` in the same line. Just follow the rules.

Comment: @matt The compiler will definitely let you call alloc on its own, and let you pass the result to another method that calls init. (It's horrible, but I've seen it done and it worked. As long as you have one alloc + one init).

Comment: If second line is illegal then why not  compile time error or at least compiler should give waring

Comment: The compiler is not required to emit diagnostics for undefined behavior (although it is certainly helpful when it does). Perhaps the [undefined behavior sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) can detect a duplicate `init`; I haven't tried it. You can enable UBSan in the Diagnostics tab of the Xcode scheme editor.

Comment: @gnasher729 It's wrong. It is not in fact the same to apply the `init` to the `alloc`-ed object in a different line.

Comment: @matt To split alloc init is wrong as a pattern, sure.  But not wrong or undefined.  Both `+alloc` and `-init` are method dispatches like any other method dispatch and there is absolutely nothing special about them.  (And, of course, calling `init` multiple times is, in fact, totally wrong and undefined).

Comment: If you goal is to write shorter code, you could use `[NSString new];` instead  of `[[NSString alloc] init];`.

Answer (score 4):

It is undefined behavior to call `init` on an already-initialized object. From the [ARC documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics-of-init):

> It is undefined behavior for a program to cause two or more calls to `init` methods on the same object, except that each `init` method invocation may perform at most one delegate init call.

What you are doing could crash your program or lead to data corruption. Don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

The "init" method expects an object that is initialised by setting all members to 0 or nil, nothing else. Like the result of [SomeClass alloc].

Calling init twice can give you all kinds of nasty side effects. For example, if the first init allocated memory, it is highly likely that the second init will cause a memory leak. Worse things can happen. And if you don't see anything bad happening now, you can bet something bad will happen in the next MacOS or iOS version.